# How to specify parameters for a silent yum installation process?

Tags: yum

When installing a package with yum, I am asked for a serial number and token during the installation process.

Can you already specify this with the yum install command so that you get a silent installation process of the package?

Answer (score 0):

From `yum --help`, I couldn't find any such command

edit: While this wasn't your exact question, `yum -y install "packagename"` will install a package assuming each yes/no prompt is "yes".